# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}dx
\end{align}
$$
Convergence at $x=0.$

Since, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ so $0$ it is not a point of infinite discontinuity, hence the integrand is convergent at $0$.

Convergence at $x=\infty.$

Since, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 0$ so $\infty$ it is not a point of infinite discontinuity, hence the integrand is convergent at $\infty$.

Will this be sufficient to prove that the integrand is convergent at $\infty$?

Comment: @RRL I've edited the question. Please review it again.

Comment: Choudary: (1) In the real number system $\infty$ is not a point so the "point of infinite continuity" terminology is not relevant -- particularly with respect to convergence of an improper integral. (2) If you are referring to the fact that  $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ which is obviously true, then this alone does not guarantee convergence of the improper integral. In this case the integral happens to converge.

Answer (score 3):

No, because you could use the same argument when you replace $\sin(x)$ with $\frac{x}{x+1}$, but the statement is obviously false in this case.

Comment: But then why that argument was sufficient for x=0 ?

Comment: Because $0$ is a “finite point”, that is, it has a neighborhood on which bounded functions are integrable.